# How to save object to "resteasy" application scope without "spring" usage?

Tags: resteasy

Do you know how to set object to resteasy framework without using spring.
For example I have service :

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {

   private MyDBconnection db = new MyDBconnection();

   ...

}
```

How can I save db connection object to application scope for all webservers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't save one db connection to be shared amongst multiple physical servers. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking. I would recommend sharing the connection/pool on each server. The easiest thing you can do is a simple singleton. However, I would recommend you use Guice https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/ so that you can do something like this wherever you need it.

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
   @Inject
   private Connection db;

   ...
}
```

and then you can define a guice module similar to this

```
public class DatabaseModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        ...
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Connection provideConnection() {
        MyDBConnection connection = new MyDBConnection("jdbc:mysql....");
        connection.setSomeCustomStuff(someCustomStuff);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I know that currently, resteasy only supports Guice 2.0. If you can live with that cool, if not, I can help you get Guice 3.0 integrated with resteasy because I've done it myself and it's working well.